# How can i tell visual studio to rebuild project when dependant library has been rebuilt

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dependencies, static-libraries

In my solution i have two projects.
One is a library that generates a .lib file on build.
The other is a test application using the library.

I have set the test project to be "dependent" on the library project.

However when i make changes to the library and press F5 to run the sample, it does not rebuild the sample. The dependency option only seem to make sure that the library is built when running the sample.

"On run,when projects are out of date" is set to "always build".

I'm using vs12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have set the Test project dependant on the Library but for this scenario you want that reversed.
Visual studio will not allow you to have a circular reference, so you will have to remove the project dependency for Test to Library and re-add it as Library to Test while you are working in this way.
The most common scenario would be a client app(Test) that is dependant on the Library and any changes on the Library would require a manual rebuild of the client, due to the fact the Library change may have broken signatures, types etc.